# A dense subset of $C(\mathbb T)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ If $f_n(\theta)=\cos^n{\theta}$ for all $\theta \in [-π,π].$
Show
$$
S= \text{span}\{\tau_{\alpha}f_n | n\in \mathbb N, \alpha \in [-π,π]\}
$$
is dense in $C(\mathbb T).$

Here, $\tau_{\alpha}f_n$ is translation of $f_n$ by $\alpha.$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ I'm trying to show that set of all trigonometric polynomials is contained in $S.$

Now, using $Cos{\theta}=(e^{i{\theta}}+e^{i{\theta}})/2$ and expanding $f_n$ by binomial expansion, it isn't helping much to show that trigonometric polynomials are there .

Any small hint ?
Thanks in adv.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the [Stone Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)?

Comment: The easiest way to show that $S$ contains the trigonometric polynomials (directly) is to use [the Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Comment: Yes, we're allowed to use Stone-Weierstrass .

Comment: Can u please write in some detail how to use Chebychev Polynomials ?

Comment: For your definition of $\Bbb N$, is $0 \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: Ok, let's assume that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $0 \in \Bbb N$, so that $S$ contains a non-zero constant function. To show that $S$ contains the trigonometric polynomials, it suffices to show that it contains the functions of the form $\cos(k\theta)$, $\sin (k \theta)$ for $k \in \Bbb N$.

Let $T_n$ denote the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind. We can see that $S$ contains $\cos(k \theta)$ because
$$
\cos(k \theta) = T_k(\cos \theta)
$$
is a linear combination of functions of the form $f_n$ for $n = 1,\dots,k$. On the other hand, we note that
$$
\sin(k \theta) = \cos(k \theta - \pi/2) = (\tau_{\pi/2} \circ T_k\circ \cos) (\theta).
$$
Thus, $\sin(k\theta)$ is a linear combination of functions of the form $\tau_{\pi/2} f_n$ for $n = 1,\dots,k$.